# Why is my query result not being printed?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
package jdbc;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.*;

public class Driver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try { 
            Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:80/entries",
                                                            "root",
                                                            "NULL");
            Statement mystmt = myConn.createStatement();
            ResultSet myRs = 
                 mystmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `entries` WHERE word LIKE '%ad' OR word LIKE '%act'");      
            while(myRs.next()) {   
                System.out.println(myRs.getString("word"));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Above is my code liked to an sql database of the English dictionary.  Why is it that when I run this code my query results are not being displayed?

Comment: Because there is no result to your SQL statement ?

Comment: There is a reusult when I do the same query in phpmyadmin

Comment: java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try runing this query on Sql Server. I feel there are no records that match your filtering creteria defined in where clause.